# How to add tikz images to a latex document created via sphinx

Tags: tikz-pgf, python, sphinx

What is the best way of adding tikz images to a latex document created via sphinx. Is there some kind of specific library

Answer (score 1):

Install the Sphinx TikZ extension:

```
pip install sphinx-tikz
```

And in the conf.py add the extension

```
extensions = ['sphinx_tikz']
```

use the directive .. tikz:: in the documents and add the tikz picture code

```
.. tikz::

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    \end{tikz picture}
```